# Database design for Subscription, Coupons and Plans

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, myisam

I have searched a lot in SO and SE but I did not get anything particularly about this kind of database design with coupon codes included. Please take a look at this problem.

I am developing a website in which I sell a service. People buy this service in advance (Pre-paid).

I sell that service in four plans

`Monthly plan`,

`3 months plan`,

`6 months plan` and

`yearly plan`.

But as encouragement for people to use my service initially, I want to give them a free coupon code(One or more). So that they can redeem in their accounts and use.

Coupons codes can be

`Monthly Coupon Code`,

`2 months Coupon Code`,

`3 months Coupon Code` and so on.

Each account will have an `account_id` in the user table.

I am struggling a lot to link This subscription model to coupons and Plans. I am a beginner at this kind of database design. Put me in a correct path.

Comment: Plan is a complex attribute of Subscription. Coupon is an entity linked to a Subscription as N:1.